# writing to csv but not getting desired formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to remove quoting all together and when I write to my csv file I'm getting an extra \ between the name and ip.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        info = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=',', escapechar='\\')
        for json_object in json_data:
            if len(json_object['names']) != 0:
                name = json_object['names'][0]
                ip = json_object['ip_address']
                combined = (name + ',' + ip)
                print combined
                info.writerow([combined])
```

this is what I'm seeing in my csv file:

```
ncs1.aol.net\,10.136.0.2
```

the formatting i'm trying to achieve is:

```
ncs1.aol.net,10.136.0.2
```

Comment: Aside: since you're using python 2 (despite the python-3.x tag), you shoulduse `open("test.csv", "wb")`, not `"w"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write the row yourself, thats the point of using `csv`. Instead of creating `combined` just use:

```
info.writerow([name, ip])
```

Currently you're writing a **single item** to the row and that means the module is escaping `,` for you and you get `\,`.

Comment: Thanks. I've also notice if doing a escapechar='\b' also fixed the issue

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, its wrong. This is not how you use the csv module. You're missing the point.

Answer (score -1):

You could also just strip your combined expression:

```
combine=combined.strip('\')
```